# sizing a flexbox within a flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox, sizing

I have flexbox that I want to place two more flexboxes in.

```
.Summary_Row{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
    }

.col_left{ order:1; width: 33%; display:flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center;}
.col_center{order:2; width: 33%; display:flex; justify-content: center;  border-right: 2px solid #d3d3d3; border-left: 2px solid #d3d3d3; text-align: center;}
.col_right{ order:3; width: 33%; display:flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center;}


    .int_row{
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-align-items: center;
     align-items: center;
     -webkit-justify-content: center;
     justify-content: center;
     -webkit-flex-flow: row;
     flex-flow: row;
     width: 100%;
    }


#inside_left{order:1; display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 25%;}
#inside_right{order:2;  display:flex; flex-flow: column; justify-content: center; width: 75%; text-align:left;}
```

In my CSS above, I have a flexbox (summary_row) that is split into three equal columns.  For col_right, I want to further split that into two more boxes side by side, one taking up 25% and the other 75% of col_right.  I have int_row which I thought should contain inside_left and inside_right, but don't know if that's superfluous.  Even though I have int_row set to 100%, the width actually doesn't extend the even close to the full width of col_right.

[image]

Blue in the image above is int_row and green is inside_right.  Notice that the blue doesn't come close to being 100% of the width.  I basically don't want the image and green to overlap.  I'm thinking if the width is extended more, the overlap wouldn't occur.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this or if I'm even thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Add your HTML also for better understanding with a fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made [a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORawbX?editors=1100) for you on CodePen.

**html**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="row__left">.row__left</div>
  <div class="row__center">.row__center</div>
  <div class="row__right">
    <div class="row__right-a">.row__right-a</div>
    <div class="row__right-b">.row__right-b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: .5em;
}

.row__left,
.row__center,
.row__right {
  flex: 0 0 33.3333333%;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row__right {
  display: flex;
}

.row__right-a {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.row__right-b {
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

You did not need the extra .int_row element. Because a flex item (child) can also be a flex container.

You should also use flex-basis and flex-grow instead of width when trying to make grids with flexbox. I used the shorthand flex property. It's always a good idea to use the flex shorthand property because it forces you to set the flex-grow, shrink and basis value. Some browsers (IE) don't have the right default values so that will save you some trouble.

Also, [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the go to article to get started with Flexbox.